# To show $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and evaluating integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given that $\alpha$ is monotonic increasing on $[0,1]$ and $ 0\leq p \leq 1 $ also $\alpha$ is continuous at $p$ given $f(p)=1 ,  f(x)=0 \forall x \neq p $ 
I need to show that $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and that $\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha = 0 $

For showing $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ can I use the theorem of finite discontinuities of $f$ and $\alpha $ being continuous at those discontinuities of $f$  ?

For showing $\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha = 0 $

My solution was by trying  : $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and thus $$\int_{0}^{1} fd\alpha = \int_{0}^{p} fd\alpha + \int_{p}^{1} fd\alpha $$
But I feel this approach is wrong.

What can be done here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ with a subinterval $[p- \delta,p+ \delta]$ when $0 < p < 1$. A similar appropriate partition can be selected if $p = 0,1$.

Since $\alpha $ is continuous at $p$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - p| < \delta $, then $|\alpha(x) - \alpha(p)| < \epsilon/2$.

Hence, denoting upper and lower Riemann-Stieltjes sums as $U(P;f,\alpha)$ and $L(P;f,\alpha)$, respectively, we have

$$0= L(P;f,\alpha)\leq L\int_{0}^{1}f\, d\alpha \leq U\int_{0}^{1}f\, d\alpha\leq U(P;f,\alpha)= \alpha(p+ \delta)-\alpha(p-\delta)\\ = |\alpha(p+ \delta)-\alpha(p)| + |\alpha(p)-\alpha(p-\delta)|< \epsilon.$$

Therefore $f$ is integrable and the integral equals $0$, since the upper and lower integrals are both equal to $0$.